# Convert NSXMLParser Object to NSString

Tags: ios, nsstring, afnetworking, nsxmlparser

I am making a request using AFNetworking to an endpoint which returns XML Response. The response always returns a `200` status code even if it is logically failed. In this case the response body either returns `0` if failed or `1` if successful.

I am using `[AFXMLParserResponseSerializer serializer]` to serialize the response which returns an `NSXMLParser` object as response in the success block of the request.

I need to parse this `NSXMLParser` object and convert it to `NSString` so that I can check whether the request failed or succeeded.

I tried parsing the response like this

In the success block

```
NSXMLParser *xmlResponse = response;
xmlResponse.delegate = self;
[xmlResponse parse];
```

Then in the delegate

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {
  if ([string isEqualToString:@"0"]) {
    // Whatever stuff I want to do
  }
}
```

But I think this is not the correct way. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: What's your current code for parsing?

Comment: @Larme I tried 

In the success block
NSXMLParser *xmlResponse = response;
xmlResponse.delegate = self;
[xmlResponse parse];

Then in the delegate
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {
  if ([string isEqualToString:@"0"]) {
    // Whatever stuff I want to do
  }
}

Comment: But I think this is not correct